# How can I specify install order of prerequisites of Visual Studio ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, clickonce, setup-deployment

I am using VS 2022, and I use ClickOnce to publish my app.

My prerequisites are Crystal Report SP33, MS Access 2016 runtime, and .NET Framework 4.7.2.

When I run ClickOnce, the Crystal Report prerequisites runs first, but it requires .NET Framework on the machine to be successful.

I need ClickOnce to install .NET Framework first and then Crystal Report.

How can I make ClickOnce install the .NET Framework before installing other prerequisites?

This is my CrystalReport Bootstrapper package `product.xml` file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is  prerequisites option in project -> properties to download components.
[image]